# How can I customize how Unity resolves instances?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I need to build up the name of the instance to resolve at runtime, based on outside conditions.

Is there an extension point in Unity that I can use to do this or should I use a factory?

For example:

```
container.RegisterType<IStrategy, FooStrategy>("FooStrategy");
container.RegisterType<IStrategy, BarStrategy>("BarStrategy");

var foo = container.Resolve<IStrategy>(); // would like to extend here to select the correct type to resolve.
Assert.IsTrue(foo.GetType() == typeof (FooStrategy));
```

Comment: And which information do you have during resolve to make that decision? The container can't just guess what you need.

Comment: @Steven, this is why I need to extend it, I will need to add some logic about how to resolve the IStrategy types.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to use as the driving data for which instance to resolve -- as Steven said, Unity can't just guess at it..

You could use your logic to just resolve by name I suppose, that would look like this (From MSDN);

```
// Create container and register types
IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, DataService>("Data");
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, LoggingService>("Logging");

// Retrieve an instance of each type
IMyService myDataService = myContainer.Resolve<IMyService>("Data");
IMyService myLoggingService = myContainer.Resolve<IMyService>("Logging");
```

If you have more complex logic, you could also go with a custom resolver. See here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250036(v=bts.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250036%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)